# How to downgrade and install ansible 1.9.4 on a mac

Tags: macos, ansible

So due to some strict versioning requirements I need to downgrade my version of Ansible from `2.1.1.0` to `1.9.4`

How can I do this (preferably with brew)?

If not with brew, then [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansible/1.9.4) may be an option.  Otherwise I have heard that using virtual env may also be a good option so that I can easily run version 2.1.1.0 or 1.9.4 similar to the manner in which rbenv works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I vote for `virtualenv`. But if you want to install ansible 1.9:

```
$> brew uninstall ansible
$> brew search ansible
ansible
ansible@1.9
ansible@2.0
...
$> brew install ansible@1.9
```

Comment: 09/2020: brew search only returns `ansible ansible-lint terraform-provisioner-ansible ansible-cmdb ansible@2.8`

Answer (score 9):

```
$> pip remove ansible

$> pip install ansible==1.9.4

$> ansible --version

     ansible 1.9.4
```

configured module search path = None

Comment: In my case it worked as I was able to see it through `pip list | grep ansible`, but I also had to add to my PATH: ```echo export PATH=\$PATH:`python -m site --user-base`/bin | tee -a ~/.bash_profile``` and reopen the Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `pip`, you can use

```
pip install ansible==<version-number>
```

This will uninstall old version and install the new one.

This logs are from my local machine when I downgraded my version from `2.7.4` to `2.4.2`

```
Installing collected packages: ansible
  Found existing installation: ansible 2.7.4
    Uninstalling ansible-2.7.4:
      Successfully uninstalled ansible-2.7.4
  Running setup.py install for ansible ... done
Successfully installed ansible-2.4.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed ansible with pip, the use the following command.

`pip uninstall ansible`

*NOTE* after you use it still possible to run ansible and get the help commands which shows that it is not uninstalled properly. See  https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/46337.

Required to execute the command as root.